# How do i install python packages without any lib requirements

Tags: python, installation, automation, package

I am writing a Speech-to-Text script right now and it needs A TON of python librarys. This script has to be useable on every PC you start it on, so i need automation for the installation of these libs. I don't want to make the installation through another script in what ever language (batch, vbs, bash, ...) there is but in python.

My Problem:
I can't find any information about how to check if a package is installed or not without using some python librarys (that are most likly not installed).
Some use subprocess, others importlib but all of them are not installed by default when installing python

code should look like:

#1

```
try:
    import package
except ImportError:
    (code that installes the package)
```

#2 Even better would be a loop

```
for x in package_list:
    try:
    import x
except ImportError:
    (code that installes the package)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found the answer myself and wanted to share it with you all.

The way to automate installing packages in python without other additional librarys is to just use the standard library of python with the package `os`.

We can use a command like `pip install {package}` and run it with `os.system(command)`.

Pip is installed standalone from version 3.4 upwards so there is no problem with that. Knowing if a package is installed can be automated with raising the error through a `try` `except`

```
try:
    import numpy
except ImportError:
    os.system("pip install numpy")
    import numpy
```

Even better would be a requirements.txt file, so that we can just do `os.system("pip install -r requirements.txt")`